# How to encrypt and decrypt all files in a directory with python 3?

Tags: python, cryptography

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import os
from os import walk

f = [ ]
path = os.getcwd()
print (path)
global dirnames
global filenames
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(path):
    print (dirnames)
    print (filenames)
```

Comment: Please add some question/description. And edit your question properly , I maybe able to answer your question then.

Comment: 1) figure out how to encrypt one file. 2) figure out how to get all files of a directory. 3) combine the above.

Comment: Sorry. New to stack overflow. but I solved it, thanks. I can now Encrypt every file in a directory, but I need to run it multiple times to decrypt every file that got decrypted. I will post the new program later.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning, that using the same IV for all files is a very bad idea (depending on the use-case).